# How to automatically import weekly Excel data from email attachment to a google sheet?

Tags: import, scripting, google-sheets, google-docs

Every week I get an .xls/.csv attachment in my email which has data. I then upload the data to Confluence from a Google Sheet. How can I have the .xls attachment automatically put data into the Google Sheet? Is there a script I can use? The attachment never has the same name I think.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script I did for someone else recently.  I think it gets files in a folder and appends them to a sheet and then renames the old files to filename.old so that it won't load them again next time the function is called.

```
function appendingCSV() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var drng = sht.getDataRange();
  var lastRow = drng.getLastRow();
  //var data = loadFile();
  var data = loadFiles();
  var dataA =Utilities.parseCsv(data);
  if(dataA.length>0)
  {
    var rng = sht.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, dataA.length, dataA[0].length);
    rng.setValues(dataA);
  }
  else
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No Data Returned from LoadFiles');
  }
}

function loadFiles(folderID)
{
  var folderID = (typeof(folderID) !== 'undefined')? folderID : 'FolderID';
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = fldr.getFiles();
  var s='';
  var re = /^.*\.csv$/i;
  while (files.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next();
    var filename = file.getName();
    if(filename.match(re))
    {
      s+=file.getBlob().getDataAsString().split('\n').splice(1).join('n') + '\n';//this was an attempt to strip off the headers. I don't know if it worked or not.
      //s += file.getBlob().getDataAsString() + '\n';
      file.setName(filename.slice(0,-3) + 'old');
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```